# Removing output of low pass filter when turning off power

Tags: filter, active-filter, passive-filter

I'm constructing a presence detect circuit using a pulse modulated signal of 5 kHz and an infrared transmitter and receiver.

The 5 kHz signal drives an infrared transmitter through a 3904 NPN transistor.

This signal is received by an infrared receiver in reverse bias mode using a 5V and 3904 NPN transistor. The receiver is located at 10 cm from transmitter. This signal after the transistor amplification is fed to a simple RC filter and it is successfully filtered (green signal in attached.)

If there is physical interruption to the path of the signal, the pulse will be high as I'm inverting the the transistor and RC filter signal using hex inverter Schmitt trigger IC.

[image: Schematic]

[image: RC Filter false positive output at shutdown]

My problem is, when the circuit loses power / it is turned off, it has a spike (red signal in the attached image) which may create a false positive for other connecting circuits.

What I understood of this, this behavior natural of such circuit as we can imagine when transmitter is turning off, the signal is turning off and filtering circuit thinks that pulses signal is not received so it is physical interruption for a short amount of time at the shutdown because of power stored in the capacitors in power supply as well as RC network.

I want to modify my circuit so I don't get such spike at shutdown and if there is any spike, its voltage level is low enough not to trigger false pulse out (presence detected.)

I searched the internet and forums but I have not been able to find any lead on this. I also tried using an active filter but got same problem.

I thought of even logic gates to tackle this problem using transmitter signal and receiver signal but because a quick thought stopped me doing this as power supply capacitors will keep circuit alive for few microseconds or milliseconds and I'll end with shutdown spike with that modification, too.

Comment: Your time scale has no units. How wide is the spike, and what is the normal minimum pulse width? Please show a schematic of the receiver.

Comment: Not words, but a schematic. Don't be lazy.

Comment: @BruceAbbott Schematic added for whole circuilt. The spike width is around 200 ms (196 ms measured). The time scale in attached image is in seconds.

Comment: @Andyaka. Sorry, I had no proper schematic so just made one in KiCad.

Comment: This circuit responds to daylight as well as 5 kHz. If you modify the circuit to respond *only to 5 kHz*, its turn-on and turn-off spikes will likely be very different, and require different solutions.

Comment: @glen_geek. I am using a receiver photodiode that has visible light filter. It will get infrared from sunlight and other sources so i modulated it to block those effects. What solution do have in mind or can you lead me somewhere to look into? Thanks!

Comment: Is the spike coming from Q1, alone, or is it generated from D2-Q3, or does it come from C1 discharging (diode with grounded anode should help), or is it a fluke with the power supply that triggers the Schmitt? And where in the schematic you posted are the two signals from?